# problem about closing idle connection for simple http server with netty

Tags: http, netty

we are setting up a simple http server with netty, just like the example in netty source code.

As we know, in http 1.1, the server didn't close the tcp connection after write response to client, so we use the IdleStateHandler to close the idle connection after certain time, 30 seconds, eg. the code is like below.

```
public class MyChannelInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<Channel> {
      @Override
     public void initChannel(Channel channel) {
         channel.pipeline().addLast("idleStateHandler", new IdleStateHandler(0, 0, 30));
         channel.pipeline().addLast("myHandler", new MyHandler());
     }
 }

 public class MyHandler extends ChannelDuplexHandler {
      @Override
     public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
         if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
             ctx.close();
         }
     }
 }
```

This worked as expected which means the server will close connection after 30 seconds after last response.

But, the problem is, if the server is handling a really slow request, so the processing time is greater than 30 seconds, the IdleStateHandler would close the connection in this situation, which we think is unexpected.

Is this the expected behavior? how sophisticated http server like tomcat/jetty handle this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your handler to remove the IdleStateHandler from the pipeline when it starts the long request and add it back on completion.

Comment: Nicholas, what I mean is for general purpose, not for a specific case.